# How to view database on root device ?

Tags: android, database, root, tablet

I want to see my database structure on my tablet (samsung Tab 2 10.1). I have root my device, but when I want to see my database in `ddms` view on my eclipse, folder `data` didn't open.

Is there any solution for my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can copy your sqlite database with `adb` from your device

1. connect your phone to pc (usb, debug enabled...)
2. `adb devices` list your connected phones
3. `adb -s deviceName pull /data/data/your.app.name.space/databases/your-db-name.db`

if you don't know hows the name of your db use the `adb shell`

`adb -s deviceName shell`

than list the files in your databases folder like this

`ls /data/data/your.app.name.space/databases/`

than you have the sqlite database you can browse with some sqlite tools

Answer (score 0):

One alternative approach for this requirement is to create database on SD card.

```
SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
```

Here you can give sd card's path in DB_PATH. Now your database is easily viewable without even root required.